# Does GAE/Java offer any brute force protection if you don't use Google Accounts for authentication?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, brute-force, google-account

I'm making a Java web app on Google App Engine.

Do I need to roll my own brute force protection for my login system - since I'm not using Google Accounts for the user accounts in my system?

Or are there are built-in features that make it easier or don't require me to do everything from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing authentication yourself, there's no way for App Engine to know what you're providing is a signin form, as opposed to anything else, so there's no way for it to protect against brute-forcing attempts. As a result, you'll have to implement it yourself.

As an alternative to Google accounts, though, you should consider the built-in OpenID support. Give serious thought to using one or the other - your users are likely to be ill-served if you insist they create yet another account from scratch just for your site.